# Hide or show all divs for a certain value of a data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to use HTML5 valid markup here, so instead of adding to values to class I want to use the data-*="" to show/hide certain divs.

```
<div class="randomclass" data-chattingto="cheesecake"></div>
<div class="randomclass" data-chattingto="milkshake"></div>
<div class="randomclass" data-chattingto="cheesecake"></div>
<div class="randomclass" data-chattingto="milkshake"></div>
```

I can get the value of data-chattingto like so:

```
$("div").data("chattingto");
```

and I can hide/show a div with a certain **class** like so:

```
$(".randomclass").hide();
```

But how do I hide all divs with the **data-chattingto value** of **cheesecake**?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply use attribute-equals notation:

```
$('div[data-chattingto="cheesecake"]').hide();
```

And a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VpkrX/), kindly provided by [CrunchyV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909219/hide-or-show-all-divs-for-a-certain-value-of-a-data-attribute/11909233#comment15855637_11909233).
References:

- [`[attribute="value"]` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Comment: Just a note - using jQuery's `.data()` to change the value won't update the attribute, so if you need to modify the values use `.attr()`

Comment: Thank you very much! :) That was very helpful, I just couldn't figure it out myself :)

Answer (score 1):

That would be:

```
$('div[data-chattingto = "cheesecake"]').show();
```

And

```
$('div[data-chattingto = "cheesecake"]').hide();
```