# How to create an array of divs with a certain custom data attribute using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bunch of divs on a page that have a custom data attribute of "data-type"

```
<div id="155544" data-type="form" data-form-id="155544">

<div data-type="question" data-question-id="119709" data-mandatory="True"></div>
<div data-type="question" data-question-id="119710" data-mandatory="True"></div>

</div>


<div id="155554" data-type="form" data-form-id="155554">

<div data-type="question" data-question-id="119711" data-mandatory="True"></div>
<div data-type="question" data-question-id="119712" data-mandatory="True"></div>

</div>
```

Thats basically the code, I've just taken out the actual content to avoid confusion.

I want to use Javascript to find out how many divs have the data-type of "form" in order for me to do something with them.

I have found this [Hide or show all divs for a certain value of a data attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909219/hide-or-show-all-divs-for-a-certain-value-of-a-data-attribute) Which is similiar to what I want to do, except I'm trying to not use jQuery.

Any solutions?

EDIT: I should also mention that I am trying to not directly use the divs "id" as those are created dynamically

Answer (score 2):

Without using JQuery, you might use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll)

```
elementList = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-type="form"]');
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/nTDu2/) (prints their number)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `querySelectorAll` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) to get a Nodelist, which you can turn into an array (and loose goodies like `.namedItem()`) if you want:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-type="form"]');
var arrayOfDivs = Array.prototype.slice.apply(divs,[0]);
```